# SQL Server 2012: Login failed for user 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService'.; 28000

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am using Analysis services in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 on Windows 7.

I tried to create Mining models and process it. I am getting the following error while processing it.

> *OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error:
>
>   Login failed for user 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService'.; 28000.*

How to correct this and process the model successfully?

Answer (score 34):

I recently encountered a similar error.

My error was fixed by creating a new login in ssms, with the name the error gave me.

In your case it would be 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService'

You then need to check 'db_datareader' and the 'db_datawriter' in that new login's properties on the 'User Mappings' page. Check the database you are using on top and then the 'db_datareader' and 'db_datawriter'on the bottom where it sais 'Database Role Membership For: Database_Name.

Hope this helps.

---

Something you can also try is:
Go to the 'Server Manager','Configuration','Services'
Search for the 'SQL Server Analysis Services (Instance_Name)' that you use.
Go to its Properties and then the 'Log on' tab.
If it uses the option of 'This Account', make sure you use that account specified in the data source of the cube in the 'Impersonation Information' as the user name and password.

### EDIT

The reason for this usually is because the account running the service does not have the right permissions to do what is requested.

There are 2 ways to do this so far I know:

1. Change the account running the sevice to the account that has the right permissions.
2. Give the account that is running the service the right permissions.

Answer (score 24):

1-Run "SQL Server Configuration Manager"

2-Select "SQL Server Services"

3-Right Click "SQL Server Analysis Services" and choose properties

4-On the "log on " tab ,choose "this account".

5-Click "Browse" button , then Click "Advanced" button.

6-Click "find now" button . Now find your account in the below table and select it.

7-When you selected proper account (With sufficient permission) , return to "log on" tab

and enter your password

8-Restart service and try again your task...

I hope this could help ...

Comment: Thanks - wanted something which worked without my needing to understand it, at this stage!

Comment: Which password? I don't have any password, I try to leave it in blank but I get an error...

Answer (score 5):

I found my solution using the oposite logic of Amir.

- Run "SQL Server Configuration Manager"
- Select "SQL Server Services"
- Right Click "SQL Server Analysis Services" and choose properties.
- On the "log on " tab ,choose "Built-In Account".
- Finally select "Local System".

Though I am just running things locally to make modifications that will later be pushed to production. So if you're running locally, this solution may help.

Answer (score 2):

I had to go an extra step to Gayan Dasanayake's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33921883/641833) given above as I was still encountering permission errors when I completed all the steps.

In my case, I had to add the user 'NT SERVICE\MSSQLServerOLAPService' to the actual database as well and grant 'select' permission on all the dimension and fact tables via the 'Securables' section by right-clicking on the users properties in SMSS.

Comment: Also, on top of everything in this answer, you might need to add the `NT SERVICE\MSSQLServerOLAPService` user to server as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

Try the steps below:

Credit (JetBoy2k) : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0a1ce033-29fb-49a9-944a-ee2ea55e69a8/errors-in-the-highlevel-relational-engine-a-connection-could-not-be-made-to-the-data-source-with?forum=sqlanalysisservices

1. Set Impersonation Mode to service account by opening the Data Source configuration window in Visual Studio and selecting Use the service account in the Impersonation Information window.
2. Go into the services MMC console (Right-click on the Windows home button, select Run, and in the Run dialog window, type in services.msc and click OK).
3. Scroll down the services list in the right pane until you find the SQL Server Analysis Services service, and look in the Log On As column to find the account name that the service runs under. Copy the fully qualified account name (NT Service\SSASAccountName) and close the Services MMC window.
4. In SSMS, click on the Database that you need to access.
5. Create a login for the SSAS service account with the following SQL command:

CREATE LOGIN [NT Service\MSOLAP$SSASSERVICEACCOUNTNAME] FROM WINDOWS

6. Click on the Security folder for that database.
7. Under the Security folder, right-click on the Users folder, then click on New User on the fly-out menu.
8. In the Database User - New window, select Windows User from the User Type drop-down.
9. In the User name field, enter the AS account name.
10. Click on the ellipsis button for the Login Name field.
11. In the Select Login window, enter the account name and click OK.
12. Back in the Database User - New window, enter dbo for the Default schema value, then click OK.
13. You should now see the AS service account in the Users folder.
14. Double-click on the Roles folder, just below the Users folder, and then double-click on the database Roles folder.
15. Double click on the DB-owner role. This will open the Database role properties - db_owner window.
16. In the Database role properties - db_owner window, click on the Add button below the Members of this role pane.
17. In the Select Database User or Role window, click on the Browse button
18. The AS service account will be listed in the Browse for Objects window. Select the checkbox for the account and click OK.
19. Back in the Select Database User or Role window, click OK.
20. You should now see the AS service account listed as a Role Member in the Members of this role pane of the Database role properties - db_owner window.
21. Click OK.

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing below how this error was fixed for me.

Go to Sql Server Configuration Manager.

[image]

Go to the Properties of the instances of SQL Server Analysis Services that you want to run.

[image]

Provide the proper Account Name that you have correct credentials for. In my case:

[image]

Click the "Browse" button from the image above to reach this window:

[image]

Click "Advanced..." from the image above to reach this window:

[image]

Click "Find Now" from the image above and find the user you have proper credentials for to login with:

[image]

Click "OK" from the image above. Then "OK" again from the following window:

[image]

Provide correct password for the user that you chose:

[image]

Click "OK" from the image above. Click "Yes" to restart the service:

[image]

Confirm that the service is running and process again your cube:

[image]

This time the data cube was processed successfully:

[image]

Comment: That helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Run 'Sql Server Configuration Manager' and check 'Log On As' account name of SQL Server Analysis Services (...name...).
2. Copy this account name (double click to open and then copy)
3. Open 'SQL Server Management Studio' and login to 'Database Engine'.
4. Go to Security > Logins click on 'New Login...' and give the copied name.
5. Restart servers

Should be able to deploy now.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same issue, but other people's answers does not help.

In my case I fixed like this:

1. Open SQL Server configuration manager
2. In SQL Services > Double click on SQL Server and copy the full user (in my case NT Service\MSSQLSERVER)
3. Double click on SQL Server Analysis Services
4. Paste the user with no password

**You will probably need to set "Use the service account" in your Data Source, in your project of Visual Studio**

Comment: step 4 fails because no password is apparently the wrong password