# OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, olap

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio.

I create one project of `Business Intelligence Project`

I create a `Data Source` Of `Adventure Work 2008 DW` and then i create one `Data Source View`

and then i create one `Cube`.

I can `build` and `rebuild` my project but when i want `Deploy` i get 34 error.

First error is

```
OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK 
SERVICE'.; 28000; Cannot open database "AdventureWorksDW2008" requested by the login.
The     login failed.; 42000.
```

I find this link : [SQL Server 2012: Login failed for user 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService'.; 28000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238559/sql-server-2012-login-failed-for-user-nt-service-mssqlserverolapservice-280)

but it not work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I Fix this error with verify this way :

At First open `Data Source`

[image]

Then `Edit` connection string

[image]

[image]

And then I `use specific windows ....` because I Want connect to another server for access to my `SSAS`.

[image]

Comment: Try select **Use Windows Authentication** in the **Connection Manager** window, and try again, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

This error is regarding **"NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"**, so just go to relational database and expand Security folder.

[image]

Double click on **"NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"**, it will open **"Login Properties"** wizard, go to **"User Mapping"** tab and choose the relational database that you are going to use. Give appropriate permissions and click OK.

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution was really effective! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that user (account) 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' don't have rights to SSAS Server deploy cube. Try open in SSAS instance and in properties choose 'Security' and add user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

Example 'SSAS Server Role':
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304417.aspx

Of course it would be very interesting to see you rights of account 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' in your DW database