# Exception occurs while processing SSAS cube

Tags: ssas, olap

while creating cube it show deployment as success  but while processing cube below exception occurs.

> OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService'.; 28000.

Answer (score 0):

Your SSAS service account doesn't have permissions to access warehouse DB. You can either explicitly set data source credentials in cube's data source or [grant database permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238559/sql-server-2012-login-failed-for-user-nt-service-mssqlserverolapservice-280) to NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService in MSSQL.

Comment: Thanks issue resolved by providing authentication details in impersonation tab..