# Login failed for user 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService'.; 28000

Tags: ssas, msbi

Error   10  OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService'.; 28000.

I have done settings like 
congfigation manager>sql server>logon>advanced>addeduser>restarted

but it's saying it again . Can someone help me?

Comment: Someone else posted the same question and has received a couple unaccepted answers that may be useful for you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238559/sql-server-2012-login-failed-for-user-nt-service-mssqlserverolapservice-280

Answer (score 0):

1. Open 'SQL Server Management Studio' and login to 'Database Engine'.
2. Go to Security > Logins click on 'New Login...' and give 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService'.
3. Restart servers

Should be able to deploy now.